# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while running app on device

Tags: ios, iphone, core-image

I'm developing an application using Core Image framework.Everything is working fine on simulator but when i'm running the app on device,my app gets crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on following piece of code.

```
CIFilter *myFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBumpDistortion"]; 
    [myFilter setDefaults]; 


    [myFilter setValue: [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[self.storyBoardImage CGImage]] forKey: kCIInputImageKey];//<----self.storyBoardImage is an UIImage and not being released.


[myFilter setValue: [CIVector vectorWithX:self.leftEyePosition.x Y:self.leftEyePosition.y]
                          forKey: kCIInputCenterKey];<-------Here my app crashed(EXC_BAD_ACCESS )
```

**note:I'm using ARC in my app.**

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the classes you are using, the error seems to be when you are trying to access the kCIInputCenterKey key. Is it created on your device?

Comment: its not throwing any error description on debug area just EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0x0) on the  line of code

Comment: can you step in CIVector? seems to you are passing invalid inputs to it .

Comment: If it is on Device only, then check with your resources_Names (Case Sensitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that kCIInputCenterKey isn't available on IOS. As you can see in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIFilter/setDefaults), it is only avaiable for OSX 10.5 and later.

That's probably the reason why it works on the simulator and not on the device itself.

Comment: thats true i also went through that doc what should i use for centre of area in iOS?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CIFilter. I can't really help you with that!

Comment: thanks cubia it was not answer but you helped me to sort out the issue

Comment: @ JohnD How "it was not answer"? I see that @Cubia gave the correct answer... exactly as you say and you in answer below

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved the issue was: I was using `kCIInputCenterKey` for the input key  centre of radius, but `kCIInputCenterKey` supports by OSX only not by iOS,therefore it was working fine on simulator but not on device.

i changed `kCIInputCenterKey` with `@"inputCenter"` and it worked.